# Insert var into string Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```
    var pseudo = $('.user-pseudo').text();

    if($(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").length) {
        $(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").addClass('yeah');
    }
```

I want to put pseudo into the contains element but it does not work, the class is not added.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What happen when you `console.log($(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").length)`? Does it return number other than 0?

Comment: Condition at 

`if($(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").length) {` 

returns `false` ?

Comment: I bet you're just not being thorough much. Post the values of `pseudo` and `$(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").length` please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`console.log(pseudo);`
and then hardcode the value of pseudo and do:
`console.log($(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('hard-coded-value')"))`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `:contains()` selector is [**Case-sensitive**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Consider the following [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0jcf3jmz/)

```
<span id="test1"> My pro text </span>
<span id="test2"> my pro text </span>
<span id="content"> I do have My pro text here </span>

$(function(){
    var txt1 = $("#test1").text(); // My pro text
    var txt2 = $("#test2").text(); // my pro text
    var length1 = $("#content:contains('"+txt1+"')").length; // 1..
    var length2 = $("#content:contains('"+txt2+"')").length; // 0..
})
```

**Alternative approach:**

To force avoiding Case-sensitive issue, you can always use another approach like,

```
var pseudo = $('.user-pseudo').text();

$contentDivs = $(".view-poke .view-content div");
$contentDivs.each(function() {
    var thisText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (thisText.indexOf(pseudo.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        // Div contains the pseudo text..
        $(this).addClass('yeah');
    }
    else {
        // Div doesn't contain pseudo text..
    }
});
```

Comment: I did : $(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").addClass('yeah');     But it still not work. I alert pseudo and it display the good value

Comment: @CorentinBranquet Can you provide the full text in `pseudo` and `.view-content div` that you expect to match? And what does `$(".view-poke .view-content div:contains('"+pseudo+"')").length` return? `0 or 1`?

Comment: Full text in pseudo : "Gojira" I expect match "Gojira"

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Post the `length` that I asked. If it's `0`, then post your full code so I can help. Otherwise, your code works just fine.